# How to remove specific amount of words from a string - Python

Tags: python

I want to remove a specific amount of words from a string. For example, my string is `s = "I am a good person JOKE JOKE JOKE"` and I want to remove the last 3 words from my string. How to do that?

Comment: s.split(" ")[:-3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `split` and `join`:

```
s = "I am a good person JOKE JOKE JOKE"

print(' '.join(s.split()[:-3]))
# I am a good person
```

If I break this down to a step-by-step format, this is how it's like:

```
>>> s = "I am a good person JOKE JOKE JOKE"
>>> s.split()
['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'person', 'JOKE', 'JOKE', 'JOKE']  
>>> s.split()[:-3]                                          
['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'person']                          
>>> ' '.join(s.split()[:-3])
'I am a good person'
```

**Steps**:

- Split sentence into words using `split()`.
- Exclude last three words through list slicing.
- Join list using `join()`.

---

This is the most common way we would think solving the problem. But I could grab yet another solution:

```
print(s.rsplit(' ', 3)[0])
```

This one uses `rsplit` which takes the separator and max value as two parameters. We take the first split and which is supposedly our result.

Comment: What if I had to only cut the words after the 5th word? For example, word limit is 5, and user gave more words than 5, so what if I only want to slice the words after the 5th word? What can I do in that case?

Comment: Use `print(' '.join(s.split()[:5]))`.